# Calling Oracle stored procedures from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, odp.net

I am having problems using SP from 'C#' with 'ODP.net'.

While executing this :

```
            List<OracleParam> param = new List<OracleParam>();
            param.Add(new OracleParam("IdEstivantIn", OracleDbType.Decimal, estivant.IdEstivant, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("NomIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Nom, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("PrenomIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Prenom, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("FixeIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Fixe, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("PortableIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Portable, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("MailIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Mail, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("RueIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Rue, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("NumeroRueIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.NumeroRue, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("CodePostaleIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.CodePostal, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("VilleIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Ville, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("PaysIn", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Pays, ParameterDirection.Input));
            //param.Add(new OracleParam("PaysIn", OracleDbType.RefCursor, null, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));

            con.ExecuteReturn(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "TAMARIS.PACKAGE_EST.updateEst", param);
```

I get this error :

```
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
ORA-06512: at "TAMARIS.PACKAGE_EST", line 94
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

In my DB, the PK is a number, and all other fields are NCLOBS.

The spec of my SP is the following :

```
PROCEDURE updateEst (
      IdEstivantIn IN number,
      NomIn IN nclob ,
      PrenomIn IN nclob,
      FixeIn IN nclob,
      PortableIn IN nclob,
      MailIn IN nclob,
      RueIn IN nclob,
      NumeroRueIn IN nclob,
      CodePostaleIn IN nclob,
      VilleIn IN nclob,
      PaysIn IN nclob) IS
 BEGIN
```

With another SP, i have another problem, which I assume must be related.

The error is the following :

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTEST'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The call I make :

```
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Nom_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Nom, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Prenom_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Prenom, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Fixe_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Fixe, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Portable_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Portable, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Mail_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Mail, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Rue_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Rue, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("NumeroRue_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.NumeroRue, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("CodePostale_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.CodePostal, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Ville_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Ville, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("Pays_in", OracleDbType.NClob, estivant.Pays, ParameterDirection.Input));
            param.Add(new OracleParam("", OracleDbType.Int32, null, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));

            con.ExecuteStoredReturn(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "PACKAGE_EST.insertEst", param);
```

What have I missed ? 
Is it because I am using NClobs instead of varchars ?

I really have no idea what is going on here, but I assume it must juste be some simple error.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but if I remember well the OracleParam names should be prefixed with ":"

Comment: OracleParam is a custom class. It just wraps around OracleParameter. But i think the issue is coming from the type. While using NVarchar2, one of my issues has been solved.

Comment: Could you post your stored procedure as well? Or at least the code in the vicinity of line 94. I think your first error is related to the procedure itself rather than how you are calling it.

Comment: Also with the second query can you show us the signature of the insertest procedure if you are still having a problem with that one